# Magento 1: weird footer characters

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, magento, magento-1.9

Our client experiences weird javascript below his footer and I can't seem to find it.

I hope you guys can point me in the right direction to debug [this](https://www.inpromoshop.nl/) error.

Below the footer you can see:

> window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var
>   z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
>   d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
>   *.push(o)};z.*=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");

Which is logical because they use Zendesk Chat. However the code should not be visible and should be between tags.

If I disable the zendesk module the javascript continues to stay there.
Things I did so far:

```
1) Disable module
2) Check footer.phtml
3) Check Config->Design tab's in Magento backend
4) Search database
5) Download entire themefolder and search for the string
```

I'm getting desperate, can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Open this thing with firebug and locate the evil in Javascript tab (it has a search bar)

if it is external you may find some layout xml that appends it. post some layout xml from this Zendesk module.